# filling column in a list of dataframes with the corresponding column name from each dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have a list of dataframes like so:

```
dflist <- list(df1,df2,..)

[1]
idx_Wafer1  value
1           45.56
2           46.13
3           46.8
4           47.23


[2]
idx_Wafer2  value
1           47.56
2           44.13
3           49.8
4           49.23
```

I want to add a column named `WaferID` to each dataframe whose rows contain the valie of the name of the first column `id_wafer(n)`

Normally I would do:

```
df1$WaferID <- names(df1[1])
df2$WaferID <- names(df2[1])
etc...
```

How do I do this on a list of dataframes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is a `list`, loop over the `list` with `lapply`, `transform` to add a new column with the first column name

```
dflist <- lapply(dflist, function(dat) transform(dat, WaferID = names(dat)[1]))
```

Comment: Thank you for that answer. Just a quick followup:
If i want to rename the columns in a list of dataframes that start with the `idx` can i do something like: 
`dflist <- lapply(dflist, function(x) transform(x, names(starts_with("idx")) <- "IDX"))` ?

Comment: @thentangler we may need `setNames` or `names<-` i.e. `lapply(dflist, function(x) {names(x)[startsWith(names(x), "idx")] <- "IDX"; x})`

Comment: Thank you it worked like a charm!
Can you point me to material where I can learn more about `lapply`? It seems that there is a plethora of things we can do with `lapply` especially on listed dataframes without using for loops, but the R documentation doesn't really mention these syntaxes.

Comment: @thentangler you could check the help documentation (`?lapply`) which includes other function as well i.e. sapply, vapply and its examples.  Also, there are some SO posts (which I couldn't find it now with search) or some other resources like [this](https://www.guru99.com/r-apply-sapply-tapply.html)